# Interesting windows networking situation

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8

I have 2 PC: 1 of them runs Windows 8, second Win XP SP3. Windows 8 PC gets internet from A wifi network and shares it into internal network created by itself (which consists of 2 pc's) via switch (lets call it network B). It plays role of DHCP server: assigns ip to second computer. in A network it has ip like 192.168.1.xx and in B network it has an ip like 192.168.137.xx.

The question is..
I want to share something between B network devices. Will this be visible to network A devices? I mean, is network B visible to network A devices?

Answer (score 1):

No, because of the different IP addresses, and the assumed subnet mask (Internet Connection Sharing has class C subnet mask, right?) of 255.255.255.0, any other computers on the first scope cannot see what's on the second scope (192.168.137.xx)

Now, if you want to share a network drive on the computer that sits on both networks, your Windows 8 machine, it will be visible on both networks. But something attached to the network and configured with the same IP subnet and subnet mask should be able to communicate with others in that network.

Comment: It has a /24, which is no longer called class C since a few decades. (See CIDR).